# Search API 'sort' and 'direction' query parameters not working in nexus 3

Tags: nexus, sonatype, nexus3

We’re using Sonatype Nexus Repository PRO 3.59.0-01 in our org. and I’m trying to search for the latest snapshot artifact in a repository using the REST API , I’ve looked all over the internet and tried the solutions : [REST API enhancements](https://community.sonatype.com/t/nxrm-3-16-rest-search-and-filtering-enhancements/1586) , but it doesn’t seem to work for me .
command used:

```
curl -u user:passwd -X GET "https://<kazan_url>/service/rest/v1/search/assets?sort=version&direction=desc&repository=<repo_name>&maven.groupId=<group_name>&maven.artifactId=<artifact_name>&maven.baseVersion=<base_version>&maven.classifier=<classifier_name>&maven.extension=zip" -H "accept: application/json"
```

Is there some bug in the existing nexus version or am I doing something wrong here ?